# Set the system shell that MATLAB uses on macOS

Tags: macos, matlab, shell, environment-variables, fish

How can I set what system shell MATLAB uses on macOS?

My default shell is [`fish`](https://fishshell.com/), which causes some toolboxes not to work correctly.

According to [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/changing-environment-variables-for-shell-escape-functions.html), MATLAB takes the shell from the `MATLAB_SHELL` or `SHELL` environment variables. Unfortunately, on macOS, it does not seem to be possible to customize a user's environment variables (let me know if this is incorrect). Of course, one can change the current shell's configuration file, such as `~/.profile`, but that will only affect the shell itself. It will not affect any graphical applications that are launched. Thus, when MATLAB starts, `SHELL` is pointing to `fish` on my system. MATLAB picks up this shell. Once MATLAB has started up, it's not use to change `SHELL` using [`setenv`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setenv.html).

Is there a solution that allows me to keep `fish` as the default system shell?

I found [other questions](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/312837-change-shell-used-by-matlab) about the same, but no solution.

Comment: See if this provides some pointers: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57385/279727

Comment: if you need to set matlab startup settings, create folder ~/matlab in your home directory, and add a file named "startup.m" in that folder. You can write matlab commands to set default settings, such as defaultfonts, defaultfigurecolormaps, etc. see https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html

Comment: @FangQ It seems that using `setenv('SHELL', '/bin/bash')` in `matlabrc.m` was sufficiently early so that `system()` would pick up the correct shell.

Comment: Downvoter: care to explain? You won't prevent 'bad' questions on StackOverflow if you don't give an explanation. You will just make the site look unfriendly.